# Thermostat running past set temperature of heat

Tags: thermostat, heat, shutoff

Heat keeps running after it reaches set temp.  I have replaced the system with a new Honeywell (non-programmable) Thermostat. (I even tried that twice). Replaced the Fan Relay as well. Maintenance tech has been out and can't get it to have the problem. It works fine for 2 or 3 cycles and then continues to run until you play with the switches again.

Switching the thermostat switch to System-Off (vs Heat or Cool) did not turn off the hot air coming out of the registers (i.e. 'burner' and blower still On).

Fan switch on Thermostat was correctly set on Auto. Switching fan from Auto to On, waiting, and then setting back to Auto DID turn the furnace and blower Off. Like it 'alerted' the furnace to the fact that the temp had been reached/exceeded and it could now turn off.

Sometimes, I can't get it to turn off that way and I have to turn off the circuit breaker.

Comment: Should add make and model, maybe age of furnace to the question.  Does sound more like a control problem inside the furnace.  Dirt, loose connection, control board dying?

Comment: Does the thermostat have an anticipator that needs adjustment? See https://www.thespruce.com/thermostat-heat-anticipator-adjustment-1824756